# Node js, i can't get my browser button to get a list of teams in the json file

Tags: node.js, json, express, model-view-controller

I'm new to Node js, and i'm cuurently writing a program to fetch data from a local json file and display in the browser, but nothing happens when i click the button. Not getting errors either. The program runs as follows: 1). node app.js 2.) opens index.html on the server (127.0.0.1:3000) 3.) click the button "Get list of the team". the button has an action = "teams" and the Controller should invoke the action to fetch the teams from the json file. The Controller invokes the Model, then renders the data in the index.htm property called "teamList". Then i expect to see the teams displayed in the browser. Here is my code:

app.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
const router  = require('./routes/router');

const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("views" , "views");
app.set("view engine", "hbs");

const host = "127.0.0.1"
const port = 3000

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//app.use('/', router);


app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.render("index", {
         teamsList: ""
    })
})

app.get('/add', (req, res) =>{
    res.render("post-tal", {
        Sum: ""
    })
})

app.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`The server is running at: http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>WebApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css">
   
    <style>
        .eNavAction {cursor:pointer}
        .buttons {margin-top: 20px}
    </style>
    <script src="js/simple-helper.js"></script>
    <script src="../controller/MainController.js"></script>
    <script src="apiServer/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="apiServer/model/apiServer-model.js"></script>
    <script src="apiServer/routes/router.js"></script>
        
   <script>
        
        var Current = {};
        const Model = new TeamsModel();
        const View = new TeamView();
        const ViewTal = new TalView();
        const Controller = new MainController();

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
           // Controller.init();
           Helper.onClassClick('eNavAction', Controller.navAction);
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar is-link" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="/">
                <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:20px">My Web App</span>
            </a>
        </div>
              
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-menu">
            <div class="navbar-start">
                <a class="eNavAction navbar-item" action ="teams">Teams</a>
                <a class="navbar-item" action= "tal" href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/add">Sum</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="section">
        <div id="main-container">
            <button class="eNavAction navbar-item" action ="teams">Get list of the team</button>
            <div id="listContainer">
              
                {{teamsList}}

            </div>
           
            
        </div>
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

MainController.js:

```
class MainContainer {
        teamList = (req, res) => {
            Model.loadTeams()
            .then(function (data) {
                res.json(data);
                //res.send(data);
                res.render("index", {
                    teamList: {data}   // A property called teamList to be displayed on the browser
                })
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
    
        navAction() {
            let action = this.getAttribute('action');  
                if (action == "teams") {
                    Controller.teamList();
                }else if(action == "tal")
                Controller.calculateSum();
        }
    
    }
```

Model.js

```
class TeamsModel {
    
      async loadTeams() {
        try {
          const json = await fetch('./json/prov-nodes.json', 'utf8')
          .then(function(response){
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
          });
        }catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reconstruct your problem. First of all I show that I fixed code and get result:
[image: screenshot]

that code in `controller.js` (`Model.js`)

```
class TeamsModel {
  async loadTeams() {
    try {
      const json = await fetch('/data/prov-nodes.json')
      return json.json(); // Important! return must be in loadTeams!
    }catch (error) {
      console.log(error) // it'll never been shown!
    }
  } 
}
```

As you can see I used `'/data/prov-nodes.json'` as path. Yes now I can access to file that I had not before by `'./json/prov-nodes.json'`.
I just add two strings in app.js:

```
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/controllers')); // allows an access
app.use('/data', express.static(__dirname + '/json')); // allows an access
```

so import of scripts looks like:

```
<script src="/js/MainController.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controller.js"></script>
```

in `index.hbs` file I just do:

```
const Model = new TeamsModel();
const Controller = new MainController();
Controller.teamList()
```

I renamed `MainContainer class` to `MainController class` (just for test)

...

```
teamList = (req, res) => {
    Model.loadTeams()
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log('DATA', data); // just output to console if success
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

...

I believe that this helps you continue coding!
I'm not sure that I reconstruct your code right (models/controllers), but I have showed you how to read `json file` in express.

```
├── app.js
├── controllers           - just modules not real controllers :)  
│   ├── MainController.js
│   └── controller.js     - I think this would be a model, sorry :) 
├── json
│   └── prov-nodes.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── views
    └── index.hbs
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227007/discussion-on-answer-by-daniil-loban-node-js-i-cant-get-my-browser-button-to-g).